# SQL file generated by Visual Studio Database project require to Enable SQLCMD mode in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-project

The SQL scripts generated by Visual Studio Database project are in SQLCMD scripts form. I don't want implementation team to Enable SQLCMD mode on ( or use SQLCMD command prompt) to run the scripts but want it to run as simple SQL SCripts.

What do I need to do?

Thanks & Regards
Sumeet

Comment: I'm curious (I'm using SQL Server very rarely): why does a SQL statement for SQLCMD differ from a regular SQL statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQLCMD adds some extra capabilities, like reading environment variables or including other .sql files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx gives you a rundown, about halfway down.

Comment: Database project is generating few Variables , initialized SQLCMD way and has been further used in in the rest of the SQL Script. Though I am open to modify the scripts the way we can shed off the SQLCMD Mode dependecies but it is going to be each time manual effort over Auto generated scripts and I am shirk of adding so.

Comment: I have similar problem wit You @Sumeet . Unfortunately, they does not care with DB Project user.    https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/3664655-allow-to-generate-deployment-comparison-script-in